# Groovy Java 8 Optional Combining Statement

Tags: java, groovy, java-8

```
Object Value = "Test";
Map<String, Object> metaMapping = definition.getMeta();

return Optional.ofNullable(metaMapping).map(mm -> mm.get(String.valueOf(value))).orElse(value);
```

I am trying to convert above java 8 Code to Groovy.
It is giving me unexpected Token Error for '->'.
Can anyone provide reference.

Comment: groovy version?

Comment: Does wrapping the expression in `{}` work?

Comment: Replace `.map()` with `.map{}`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
println Optional.ofNullable(metaMapping).map{
    mm -> mm.get(String.valueOf(value))
}.orElse(value)
```

Depending on your requirements, you might also do something like this:

```
metaMapping = definition.getMeta().withDefault { key -> key }
println metaMapping.get(value)
```